# VB Agility Pack XPath select sub node in parent based on another sub nodes value

Tags: html, vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML DOM like so:

```
<div class="productcontainer">
    <div class="image jsThumbnailReplace">
        <a href="">
            <img src="/img/noimagemedium.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="productdata"
        <div class="descriptionsection">
            <div class="title">title</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the title text only if the source in the image tag contains "noimagemedium". I use Visual Studio 2010 with VB.Net and the HTML Agility pack to achieve this. The Debugger says the XPath expression is invalid.

I thought this XPath should do it but it doesn´t work:

```
//div[@class='descriptionsection']/div[@class='title'][//div[@class='productcontainer']/div[contains(@class, 'image') and contains(@class, 'jsThumbnailReplace')]/a/img[contains(@src, 'noimagemedium')]]
```

Apparently the syntax is wrong but I can´t figure it out. Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. The crux is right after the first "and". You don´t need an opening bracket, you can directly call the path. Important to note is that contains() doesn´t search through the raw Node-text, you have to specify either a text or an attribute. With that knowledge in mind I could build that XPath.

```
//div[@class='productcontainer' and div[1]/a/img[contains(@src, 'noimagemedium')]]/div[@class='descriptionsection']/div[@class='title']"
```